# Files inside archives can't be opened inside 7zip

Tags: windows-7, archiving, 7-zip

I open the archive inside 7zip, then double-click a file inside the archive to open it with the associated application, and I get "File not found" errors in the app (for example opening a image in Windows Photo Viewer).

Some times it works, but most of the times it doesn't.
I think 7zip fails to extract the file in the temporary folder or something? Is there any fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem, I generally just drag that one file out and open it from the desktop or a temp folder.

***Edit***: Seems to be a known issue. See [here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3155236&group_id=14481&atid=114481) and [here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3094818&group_id=14481&atid=114481), but there doesn't seem to be a fix for it other than the workaround we're both using.

Comment: yes I do that too, but it's really annoying :|